# Display two images with SRCSET at different screen size issue

Tags: javascript, srcset

I have looked over examples online, yet I believe I am overlooking something. I have two similar images that need to be rendered when the screen is at a different size. One image at 1440px screen size and one at 375px screen size. Right now with my code I have set the initial source to render the "mobile view" of the image, and with the srcset of the desktop view image at 1440w. When I load up live server it shows the desktop image, and not the initial source of the mobile view. So it seems to be working but missing a step.. any tips are greatly appreciated!

```
 <img
            class="future__container--img"
            src="./images/illustration-editor-mobile.svg"
            srcset="./images/illustration-editor-desktop.svg 1440w"
            alt="illustration-editor-mobile"
          />
```

So when the browser first loads it is showing the desktop.svg, but when I set the browser to 375px it still displays the desktop.svg. I first had this written in javascript ..

```
const resizeEditiorImg = () => {
  const reswidth = screen.width;
  let image = document.querySelector(".future__container--img");
  if (reswidth >= 1440) {
    image.src = "../images/illustration-editor-desktop.svg";
  } else {
    image.src = "../images/illustration-editor-mobile.svg";
  }
};
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeEditiorImg);
```

But the issue here is that when the browser first loads on desktop view, it is displaying the mobile image unless the user manually resizes the browser, which is what I believed at first. I hope this post makes sense!

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: It might help to build a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [placeholder](https://placeholder.com/) or [dummy](https://fakeimg.pl/) images to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This only work in resize browser because this code resizeEditiorImg

you need run this command resizeEditiorImg in your load page.

example

```
<body onload="resizeEditiorImg()">
```